# Insert values into Excel when message arrives in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a requirement to collect two dates from mail and insert to one Excel sheet whenever one message arrives in my Outlook 2010. I created a `rule` in Outlook which will 'run a script' whenever a massage arrives in outlook. I passed everything except part where `inserting collected data into the Excel sheet`.

I tried following code which works perfectly in VBA Excel but it seems like not with Outlook:

```
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("U:\leaveBook.xls")
Set sh = ActiveSheet ''wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each rw In sh.Rows
  If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
    sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1) = 1
    sh.Cells(rw.Row, 2) = "Name"
    sh.Cells(rw.Row, 3) = "TestData1"
    sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4) = "TestData2"
    GoTo BREAK
    End If
Next rw
BREAK:
```

I am trying to add data to next available row in Excel sheet.

Can someone help me to write the same code in Outlook VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following will require adding **Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library** or equivalent to the project via the VBE's Tools ► References command.

Your posted sample code was pretty vanilla and I've tried to maintain that 'Hello World!' style. This framework is very basic but it will perform was is asked of it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testXL()
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook, nr As Long
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("U:\leaveBook.xls")
    With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        nr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        .Cells(nr, 1) = 1
        .Cells(nr, 2) = "Name"
        .Cells(nr, 3) = "TestData1"
        .Cells(nr, 4) = "TestData2"
    End With
    wb1.Close True
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tested this with the Office 2013 Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library. If you run into compatibility confirmations, these can be bypassed with the apprpriate options in the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx).

Comment: sorry for late response, but your code helped me to save lot of time.. Thank you so much for your precious time!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify the last used row and put your new data after it. Something like:-

```
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim RowNext As Integer

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("U:\leaveBook.xls")
Set sh = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
RowNext = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

sh.Cells(RowNext, 1) = 1
sh.Cells(RowNext, 2) = "Name"
sh.Cells(RowNext, 3) = "TestData1"
sh.Cells(RowNext, 4) = "TestData2"
GoTo BREAK
```

And don't forget to save, close and disposal in the end like this (I would suggest add it it before `GoTo BREAK`):

```
wb1.Save
wb1.Close
Set sh = Nothing
Set wb1 = Nothing
```